# RxTextView.textChanges with setText on Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, rx-java2, rx-android

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
                .map(CharSequence::toString)
                .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(input -> {
                   output = //...do something with input
                   editText.setText(ouput)
                 }));
```

When I `setText(output)` it goes in loop. To set the text I first need to remove listener and then set listener again. How can I do this using *RxJava*?

Comment: Overwriting the user's text might not be the best option (what if the user is currently typing?). Otherwise, use `distinctUntilChanged` between that `map` and `debounce`.

Comment: You are right. but the requirements are so. for e.g if user input `.` I need to put `0` before that and format the text as user type like putting comma in currency value. 
7000 = > 7,000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I `setText(output)` it goes in loop. To set the text I first need to remove listener and then set listener again. How can I do this using *RxJava*?

To meet the requirement I managed to extend the [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) source code as follows.

**`EditableTextViewTextObservable.java`**:

```
public class EditableTextViewTextObservable extends InitialValueObservable<CharSequence> {
    private final TextView view;

    EditableTextViewTextObservable(TextView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeListener(Observer<? super CharSequence> observer) {
        EditableTextViewTextObservable.Listener listener = new EditableTextViewTextObservable.Listener(view, observer);
        observer.onSubscribe(listener);
        view.addTextChangedListener(listener);
    }

    @Override protected CharSequence getInitialValue() {
        return view.getText();
    }

    final static class Listener extends MainThreadDisposable implements TextWatcher {
        private final TextView view;
        private final Observer<? super CharSequence> observer;

        Listener(TextView view, Observer<? super CharSequence> observer) {
            this.view = view;
            this.observer = observer;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!isDisposed()) {
                view.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                observer.onNext(s);
                view.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDispose() {
            view.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**`EditableRxTextView.java`**:

```
public final class EditableRxTextView {
    @CheckResult
    @NonNull
    public static InitialValueObservable<CharSequence> textChanges(@NonNull TextView view) {
        return new EditableTextViewTextObservable(view);
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
EditableRxTextView.textChanges(editText)
            .map(CharSequence::toString)
            .debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(input -> {
               output = //...do something with input
               editText.setText(ouput)
             }));
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to use `editText.getText().replace(...)` as to not trigger the TextWatcher when setting the text