# RxAndroid: Manage events of interdependent objects

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have 2 editText fields editText1 and editText2.

I am using Reactive to capture when the user changes the contents of any one of them.

When this happens, I want to copy to the other field the value of the first field and vice-versa (make them interdependent).

The problem is that when I update the second field, a new event is triggered and the consumer of the second field tries to update the first one. This results on an infinite recursion.

What I need is to take in account only the events from the user, and not the events from the setText that I perform in the consumers.

```
    RxTextView.textChanges(editText1)
            .subscribe(new Consumer<CharSequence>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(CharSequence e) throws Exception {
                    editText2.setText(editText1.getText());
                }
            });

    RxTextView.textChanges(editText2)
            .subscribe(new Consumer<CharSequence>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(CharSequence charSequence) throws Exception {
                    editText1.setText(editText2.getText());
                }
            });
```

Comment: You could make use of the `EditableRxTextView` I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882291/3290339) which fixes that `RxTextView`'s drawback. Although, it's in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try wrapping your `setText()` calls in an `if` check.

If you type something into TextView A, that value will propagate to TextView B, which will then update itself. This, of course, propagates back to A... but A should already have that same value anyway. So you can check and only actually call `setText()` when the value is different.

```
public void accept(CharSequence charSequence) throws Exception {
    String before = editText1.getText().toString();
    String after = editText2.getText().toString();

    if (!before.equals(after)) {
        editText1.setText(after);
    }
}
```

So this will still go A -> B -> A, but when the value comes back to A the second time, it will be ignored, and the infinite loop will be broken.