# Text Watcher with RX Android

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm working with an ObservableField that requires to take an action after the EditText binded to this observable, have 8 characters. Any suggestions of how to make this using Rx Java?

My tries:
- I tried to work with the concept of observer, but I couldn't find a way to do this
- I read about Consumer but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case

Scenario: User have to type 8 numerical characters and call an API after the 8th character typed

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: RxBinding might help: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding

Comment: In addition to @Christopher's suggestion on using `RxBinding` you might find helpful my ["extension" on this library's `EditText` with `TextWatcher`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882291/3290339).

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter your events so you only have to manage those with a proper input. Therefore, you need the [`filter`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) operator:

```
val observable = createAnObservableFromYourEditText()
val eventsWithMoreThan8Characters = observable.filter { it.text.size > 7 }
eventsWithMoreThan8Characters.subscribe { /* it.text will always have > 7 characters */ }
```

Comment: can't use filter. I'm using ObservableField from databinding library