# Android: RxTextView.textChanges for EditText goes infinite loop

Tags: android, android-edittext, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

**What I need:** I want to observe change in `EditText` and format in some number `DecimalFormat`.

**What I'm Trying:** I'm trying to observe `EditText` with *Rx*.

**What's the Issue:** After I start typing it goes to **INFINITE** loop. Below is the code what I'm trying to do.

*ProductDetailsActivity.java*:

```
public class ProductDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
    @BindView(R.id.et_product_price)
    EditText et_product_price;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        RxTextView.textChanges(et_product_price)
            .skipInitialValue()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(str -> {

                double amount = Double.parseDouble(str.toString());
                DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###");
                String formatted = formatter.format(amount);
                et_product_price.setText(formatted);

                Log.e("mk", "output: " + formatted);

            }, throwable -> {
                Log.e("mk", "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797759/rxtextview-textchanges-with-settext-on-edittext

Comment: You might find a solution I proposed at [RxTextView.textChanges with setText on Edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882291/3290339) helpful.

Comment: Yes, Onik's solution is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I went back to `TextWatcher` to get the solution. I wrote in `onCreate` method like below.

```
et_product_price.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {

                String enteredProductPrice = s.toString().replace(",", "");

                double enteredProductPriceDouble = Double.parseDouble(enteredProductPrice);
                String formattedProductPrice = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###").format(enteredProductPriceDouble);

                et_product_price.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                et_product_price.setText(formattedProductPrice);
                et_product_price.setSelection(et_product_price.getText().length());

                et_product_price.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

This might help somebody.

Comment: Good solution! However a drawback of such an approach is that you have to set a listener from within code; in case you have several EditTexts with different "functionality", say email and phone, you'll have to set 2 listeners. The amount might grow.

Comment: Correct. It is difficult but we can have generic TextWatcher class for that@Onik

Comment: You could make use the approach I proposed. It is rather API than the generic approach.

Comment: I haven't look into it properly but I would definitely like to give a try. Once I try, I'll let you know.@Onik

Answer (score -1):

Every time you call `setText()`, even if the actual text isn't different, that will count as a "text changed" event. That means this line is the culprit:

> ```
> et_product_price.setText(formatted);
> ```

When you call that for the first time, it will trigger a text change event, so your subscriber will be triggered again. It will parse and format the double, and then call `setText()` again. And so on.

There are many ways to solve this, but fundamentally you just need to make sure that you don't call `setText()` if the "new" value is equal to the "old" value.

```
if (!formatted.equals(et_product_price.getText().toString()) {
    et_product_price.setText(formatted);
}
```

Comment: This does not alter the fact a new value will be emitted every time `new text != old text`.

Comment: I thought I wrote. The better solution would be to avoid emitting a new value at all. What if you need to cut some chars. The more chars are to be cut the more new emitions... (p.s. I wasn't downvoting).